# Trying to install Rails 6 using RVM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos

I have installed RVM successfully on my Mac and using it I have installed Ruby 2.6.3. I have set my current and default version of Ruby to be 2.6.3. Everything seems to be fine because when I enter ruby -v into the terminal it tells me I'm using ruby 2.6.3.

My problem comes when I try to install Rails 6, I'm entering:

```
gem install rails --version=6.0.0 -no-ri -no-rdoc
```

It seems to install correctly however when I try to confirm with:

```
rails -v
```

I get:

```
Rails 6 requires Ruby 2.5.0 or newer.

You're running
  ruby 2.3.7p456 (2018-03-28 revision 63024) [universal.x86_64-       darwin18]

Please upgrade to Ruby 2.5.0 or newer to continue.
```

Why am I getting this message when my ruby -v command is telling me that I am using ruby 2.6.3

Any help would be very welcome.

Comment: What directory are you in when you run `ruby -v` and what directory are you in when you run `rails -v`? If you're in an project directory there may be a `.ruby-version` file that RVM reads that automatically switches your Ruby version. Also, what shell are you using and what user are you logged in as when doing these operations? RVM installs Ruby for your current user profile only; make sure you haven't used `su` or changed shells. Order of operations should be: `echo $SHELL; cd ~; echo $HOME; whoami; rvm list; ruby -v; rails -v` -- post the output here.

Comment: Tony, was this figured out?

Answer (score 1):

You're running `ruby 2.3.7p456`. You need to set your local ruby version to `2.6.3`.

Try `which ruby` to see which ruby version is loaded.

```
rvm install 2.6.3
rvm use 2.6.3
```

You can then see which ruby is running with `which ruby`.

See the basics on the [rvm docs](https://rvm.io/rvm/basics)

As an aside, I also recommend recommend rbenv over rvm; however, you can only have one installed. If you have both installed, you're going to have a bad time.

To make sure you do not have both installed try `which rbenv`, and that should return `rbenv not found`

Please edit your original question with the output of the following commands:

1. `which -a ruby`
2. `echo $PATH` (That will help debug if your $PATH is set up incorrectly.)
3. `which rbenv`
4. `ls` (in your project directory)

Comment: which ruby outputs: /Users/tonystaunton/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/bin/ruby

Comment: which -a ruby outputs: /usr/bin/ruby

Comment: echo $PATH outputs: /Users/tonystaunton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/bin:/Users/tonystaunton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@global/bin:/Users/tonystaunton/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/bin:/Users/tonystaunton/.rvm/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/anaconda3/bin:/anaconda3/condabin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin

Comment: I agree with Dbz - using rbenv obviates the need to fiddle around with gemsets.

Comment: I've used rvm for over six years and have never had to "fiddle around with gemsets." In my experience, rbenv and its shims cause way, way more compatibility issues than using rvm. The solution to rbenv problems is always "use rvm."

Comment: @TonyStaunton please edit your original question with all of the outputs. It makes it much easier to debug because I can tell that some of the data got lost when pasting into the comment

Answer (score 0):

i also had the similar problem which i resolved by uninstalling rvm completely and then installing rbenv.